# I want to write a double quotation mark in a string, but compiler can't read it

Tags: c++, c++11

Here's my code, also I don't want to change `"` this symbol.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str = "-/"0123456789";
    cout << str;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what's your desired output? `-"0123456789`?

Comment: No, -/"0123456789

Comment: Then use `string str = "-/\"0123456789";`

Answer (score 4):

You can either use an escape sequence for the quotation mark, i.e. replace it with ", or use a raw string literal. In a raw string literal, you enclose the string using R"( at the beginning, and )" at the end.

To illustrate:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str1 = "-/\"0123456789"; //Escape sequence \"
    string str2 = R"(-/"0123456789)"; //Raw string literal
    cout << str1 << endl;
    cout << str2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and can i get raw string literal from a user?

Comment: How do you want to get it from the user? From standard input (i.e. terminal input)? Raw strings are relevant to written code, but unnecessary for data read from a file. So let's say you have code like:

`string input; cin >> input; cout << input << endl;`

If the user types in `-/"0123456789`, it will store this exactly in the string, and output it as such.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape with `\` not `/`.

`string str = "-\"0123456789";`

> -"0123456789

If you wanted to include the `/` then you can use
`string str = "-/\"0123456789";`

> -/"0123456789

In C++11 you can use a raw string

`string str = R"(-"0123456789)"`

> -"0123456789

or
`string str = R"(-/"0123456789)"`

> -/"0123456789

Comment: In your raw string examples, you are including more than 1 `"` in the literal data, so the output would actually be `"-"0123456789"` and `"-/"0123456789"`, respectively. To get the output the OP asked for, you need the raw literals to look like `R"(-"0123456789)"` and `R"(-/"0123456789)"` instead, respectively.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. I've fixed it @RemyLebeau